# Merging two arrays in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Is there a built in function in .NET 2.0 that will take two arrays and merge them into one array?

The arrays are both of the same type. I'm getting these arrays from a widely used function within my code base and can't modify the function to return the data in a different format.

I'm looking to avoid writing my own function to accomplish this if possible.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

If you can manipulate one of the arrays, you can resize it before performing the copy:

```
T[] array1 = getOneArray();
T[] array2 = getAnotherArray();
int array1OriginalLength = array1.Length;
Array.Resize<T>(ref array1, array1OriginalLength + array2.Length);
Array.Copy(array2, 0, array1, array1OriginalLength, array2.Length);
```

Otherwise, you can make a new array

```
T[] array1 = getOneArray();
T[] array2 = getAnotherArray();
T[] newArray = new T[array1.Length + array2.Length];
Array.Copy(array1, newArray, array1.Length);
Array.Copy(array2, 0, newArray, array1.Length, array2.Length);
```

[More on available Array methods on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).

Comment: What about .NET 4.0, any news?

Comment: Note that `Array.Resize` does not actually resize the array, it copies it. That's why the first parameter is by-ref (which means your first code probably won't compile).

Comment: I'd just throw out your first piece of code. It doesn't offer an advantage, and is harder to read IMO.

Comment: Please note that the order of the parameters in the second code example for Array.Copy are wrong. Use Array.Copy(array1, newArray, 0); instead.

Comment: You can also do ..   List<byte> finalArray = new List<byte>();
            finalArray.AddRange(array1);
            finalArray.AddRange(array2);
==>finalArray.toArray();

Answer (score 560):

In C# 3.0 you can use LINQ's [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to accomplish this easily:

```
int[] front = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] back = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] combined = front.Concat(back).ToArray();
```

In C# 2.0 you don't have such a direct way, but Array.Copy is probably the best solution:

```
int[] front = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] back = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

int[] combined = new int[front.Length + back.Length];
Array.Copy(front, combined, front.Length);
Array.Copy(back, 0, combined, front.Length, back.Length);
```

This could easily be used to implement your own version of `Concat`.

Comment: I like that LINQ implementation. I really need to make the jump and get into LINQ soon...

Comment: Rich, the best part about the LINQ implementation is not only is it concise, it's also just as efficient as the 2.0 version, since it works against IEnumerable.

Comment: This answer includes this way and also gives some benchmarking results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415291/best-way-to-combine-two-or-more-byte-arrays-in-c-sharp

Comment: This is probably the easiest way but this is not going to be efficient for large arrays, since Concat is implemented using foreach loops + yield (see reference source). A solution with BlockCopy will  be faster.

Comment: .Contat() is definitely the simplest. Just a tip from my experience, if you want to remove duplicates just call .Distinct() afterwards.

Comment: Just a small heads up: if you only want to iterate through the combined result, no need to convert it to an array. That final operation does an array copy. It won't have to do that if you iterate through an IEnumerable<int>. Of course, there could be good reasons to have it be an array.

Answer (score 151):

Use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
var arr1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var arr2 = new[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
var arr = arr1.Union(arr2).ToArray();
```

Keep in mind, this will remove duplicates. If you want to keep duplicates, use Concat.

Comment: CAUTION: Union will remove duplicates.

Comment: @Yogee, easy to remember as it is like in SQL and also the nomenclature is connected with sets theory.

Comment: I see Simon already mentioned the issue of Union and alternate approach he suggested. No need to discuss further about that as Simon knows what he is answering.

Answer (score 59):

If you don't want to remove duplicates, then try this

Use LINQ:

```
var arr1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var arr2 = new[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
var arr = arr1.Concat(arr2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 12):

First, make sure you ask yourself the question "Should I really be using an Array here"?

Unless you're building something where speed is of the utmost importance, a typed List, like `List<int>` is probably the way to go. The only time I ever use arrays are for byte arrays when sending stuff over the network. Other than that, I never touch them.

Comment: Big +1 here. Note that best practice is to avoid exposing `List<T>` in public APIs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/26/474010.aspx

Answer (score 11):

Easier would just be using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
var array = new string[] { "test" }.ToList();
var array1 = new string[] { "test" }.ToList();
array.AddRange(array1);
var result = array.ToArray();
```

First convert the arrays to lists and merge them... After that just convert the list back to an array :)

Comment: You are not used array directly. You used List!

Answer (score 8):

This is what I came up with. Works for a variable number of arrays.

```
public static T[] ConcatArrays<T>(params T[][] args)
    {
        if (args == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var offset = 0;
        var newLength = args.Sum(arr => arr.Length); 
        var newArray = new T[newLength];

        foreach (var arr in args)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(arr, 0, newArray, offset, arr.Length);
            offset += arr.Length;
        }

        return newArray;
    }
```

...

```
var header = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2};
var data = new byte[] { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var checksum = new byte[] {7, 0};
var newArray = ConcatArrays(header, data, checksum);
//output byte[9] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0 }
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5s0whfd.aspx) for this. It takes a source index and destination index so you should be able to append the one array to the other. If you need to go more complex than just appending one to the other, this may not be the right tool for you.

Answer (score 7):

Starting from C# 12 you may use the [Collection Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions) and *spread operator* `..`, for example:

```
int[] a = [1, 2, 3];
int[] b = [4, 5, 6];
int[] c = [..a, ..b];
```

**Note:** The feature is part of [.NET 8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0) released in Nov 2023.

Answer (score 6):

Everyone has already had their say but I think this more readable than the "use as Extension method" approach:

```
var arr1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var arr2 = new[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
var arr = Queryable.Concat(arr1, arr2).ToArray();
```

However it can only be used when bringing together 2 arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the destination array has enough space, [`Array.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will work. You might also try using a `List<T>` and its [`.AddRange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I prefer my own Language Extensions, which I add or remove at will for rapid prototyping.

Following is an example for strings.

```
//resides in IEnumerableStringExtensions.cs
public static class IEnumerableStringExtensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<string> Append(this string[] arrayInitial, string[] arrayToAppend)
   {
       string[] ret = new string[arrayInitial.Length + arrayToAppend.Length];
       arrayInitial.CopyTo(ret, 0);
       arrayToAppend.CopyTo(ret, arrayInitial.Length);

       return ret;
   }
}
```

It is much faster than LINQ and Concat. Faster still, is using a custom `IEnumerable` Type-wrapper which stores references/pointers of passed arrays and allows looping over the entire collection as if it were a normal array. (Useful in HPC, Graphics Processing, Graphics render...)

**Your Code:**

```
var someStringArray = new[]{"a", "b", "c"};
var someStringArray2 = new[]{"d", "e", "f"};
someStringArray.Append(someStringArray2 ); //contains a,b,c,d,e,f
```

For the entire code and a generics version see: https://gist.github.com/lsauer/7919764

**Note:** This returns an unextended IEnumerable object. To return an extended object is a bit slower.

*I compiled such extensions since 2002, with a lot of credits going to helpful people on CodeProject and 'Stackoverflow'. I will release these shortly and put the link up here.*

Answer (score 3):

Just to have it noted as an option: if the arrays you are working with are of a primitive type – Boolean (bool), Char, SByte, Byte, Int16 (short), UInt16, Int32 (int), UInt32, Int64 (long), UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Single, or Double – then you could (or should?) try using [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx). According to the MSDN page for the [Buffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.aspx) class:

> This class provides better performance for manipulating primitive types than similar methods in the [System.Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) class.

Using the C# 2.0 example from @OwenP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59262/577765) as a starting point, it would work as follows:

```cs
int[] front = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] back = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

int[] combined = new int[front.Length + back.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(front, 0, combined, 0, front.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(back, 0, combined, front.Length, back.Length);
```

There is barely any difference in syntax between `Buffer.BlockCopy` and the `Array.Copy` that @OwenP used, but this should be faster (even if only slightly).

Answer (score 3):

I needed a solution to combine an unknown number of arrays.

Surprised nobody else provided a solution using `SelectMany` with `params`.

```
 private static T[] Combine<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] items) =>
                    items.SelectMany(i => i).Distinct().ToArray();
```

If you don't want distinct items just remove distinct.

```
 public string[] Reds = new [] { "Red", "Crimson", "TrafficLightRed" };
 public string[] Greens = new [] { "Green", "LimeGreen" };
 public string[] Blues = new [] { "Blue", "SkyBlue", "Navy" };

 public string[] Colors = Combine(Reds, Greens, Blues);
```

Note: There is definitely no guarantee of ordering when using distinct.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example using Array.CopyTo.
I think that it answers your question and gives an example of CopyTo usage - I am always puzzled when I need to use this function because the help is a bit unclear - the index is the position in the destination array where inserting occurs.

```
int[] xSrc1 = new int[3] { 0, 1, 2 };
int[] xSrc2 = new int[5] { 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7 };

int[] xAll = new int[xSrc1.Length + xSrc2.Length];
xSrc1.CopyTo(xAll, 0);
xSrc2.CopyTo(xAll, xSrc1.Length);
```

I guess you can't get it much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else is looking for how to merge two image byte arrays:

```
        private void LoadImage()
        {
            string src = string.empty;
            byte[] mergedImageData = new byte[0];

            mergedImageData = MergeTwoImageByteArrays(watermarkByteArray, backgroundImageByteArray);
            src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(mergedImageData);
            MyImage.ImageUrl = src;
        }

        private byte[] MergeTwoImageByteArrays(byte[] imageBytes, byte[] imageBaseBytes)
        {
            byte[] mergedImageData = new byte[0];
            using (var msBase = new MemoryStream(imageBaseBytes))
            {
                System.Drawing.Image imgBase = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(msBase);
                Graphics gBase = Graphics.FromImage(imgBase);
                using (var msInfo = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image imgInfo = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(msInfo);
                    Graphics gInfo = Graphics.FromImage(imgInfo);
                    gBase.DrawImage(imgInfo, new Point(0, 0));
                    //imgBase.Save(Server.MapPath("_____testImg.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
                    MemoryStream mergedImageStream = new MemoryStream();
                    imgBase.Save(mergedImageStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                    mergedImageData = mergedImageStream.ToArray();
                    mergedImageStream.Close();
                }
            }
            return mergedImageData;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the source arrays in an array itself you can use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var arrays = new[]{new[]{1, 2, 3}, new[]{4, 5, 6}};
var combined = arrays.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();
foreach (var v in combined) Console.WriteLine(v);
```

gives

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Probably this is not the fastest method but might fit depending on usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using your own array types as opposed to the built-in .NET arrays:

```
public string[] merge(input1, input2)
{
    string[] output = new string[input1.length + input2.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
    {
        if (i >= input1.length)
            output[i] = input2[i-input1.length];
        else
            output[i] = input1[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Another way of doing this would be using the built in ArrayList class.

```
public ArrayList merge(input1, input2)
{
    Arraylist output = new ArrayList();
    foreach(string val in input1)
        output.add(val);
    foreach(string val in input2)
        output.add(val);
    return output;
}
```

Both examples are C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] SouceArray1 = new int[] {2,1,3};
int [] SourceArray2 = new int[] {4,5,6};
int [] targetArray = new int [SouceArray1.Length + SourceArray2.Length];
SouceArray1.CopyTo(targetArray,0);
SourceArray2.CopyTo(targetArray,SouceArray1.Length) ; 
foreach (int i in targetArray) Console.WriteLine(i + " ");
```

Using the above code two Arrays can be easily merged.

Answer (score 0):

Created and extension method to handle null

```
public static class IEnumerableExtenions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> UnionIfNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2)
    {
        if (list1 != null && list2 != null)
            return list1.Union(list2);
        else if (list1 != null)
            return list1;
        else if (list2 != null)
            return list2;
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] names1 = new string[] { "Ava", "Emma", "Olivia" };
string[] names2 = new string[] { "Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma" };
List<string> arr = new List<string>(names1.Length + names2.Length);
arr.AddRange(names1);
arr.AddRange(names2);
string[] result = arr.Distinct().ToArray();
foreach(string str in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to find an approach without using any libraries or functionality beyond arrays themselves.

The first two examples are mostly for reading the logic from scratch, but I also wonder if there could be performance variations depending on the sitaution.

The third example is the most practical choice.

```
// Two for-loops
private static int[] MergedArrays_1(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int[] result = new int[a.Length + b.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i = a.Length; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = b[i - a.Length];
    }
    return result;
}

// One for-loop
private static int[] MergedArrays_2(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int[] results = new int[a.Length + b.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        results[i] = (i < a.Length) ? a[i] : b[i - a.Length];
    }
    return results;
}

// Array Method
private static int[] MergedArrays_3(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int[] results = new int[a.Length + b.Length];
    a.CopyTo(results, 0);
    b.CopyTo(results, a.Length);
    return results;
}
```

Lastly, I made a fourth example, that can merge multiple arrays, using the params keyword.

```
int[] result = MultipleMergedArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree);
```

```
private static int[] MultipleMergedArrays(params int[][] a)
{
    // Get Length
    int resultsLength = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < a.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        resultsLength += a.Length;
    }

    // Initialize
    int[] results = new int[resultsLength];

    // Add Items
    int index = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < a.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        a[row].CopyTo(results, index);
        index += a[row].Length;
    }
    return results;
}
```

The way it works when using params, is that the single-dimension arrays are passed into a jagged array.

GetLength(0) returns the number of arrays contained within the jagged array.

The code first counts the Length of all the arrays, then it initializes a new array based on that size, and starts adding entire arrays into the new results array by using the CopyTo() method, while adding the Length of each added array to an index counter.

PS:  Some times it is necessary to remove empty items, or certain items, from arrays when merging.

```
private static int[] RemoveEmpty(int[] array)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0) count++;
    }

    int[] result = new int[array.Length - count];

    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0) continue;
        result[count] = array[i];
        count++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This function can be combined with the ones above.

It takes an array, counts the number of items that match zero. And creates a new array of the proper size. Then the counter is recycled and used as an index, for where to put place the input array's values into the new and smaller result array.
When an item matches zero, it skips the rest of the code in that round of the loop, and continues with the next round, without incrementing the integer counter.

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 5, we now have [AllocateUninitializedArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.allocateuninitializedarray?view=net-7.0) which can possibly add an additional (small) performance improvement for the suggested solutions:

```
public static T[] ConcatArrays<T>(IEnumerable<T[]> arrays)
{
    var result = GC.AllocateUninitializedArray<T>(arrays.Sum(a => a.Length));
    var offset = 0;
    foreach (var a in arrays)
    {
        a.CopyTo(result, offset);
        offset += a.Length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an efficient solution, you might try this one:

```
        //
    ///<summary>Join two arrays together. At least one array must exist.</summary>
    public static T[] Append<T>( this T[] a1, T[] a2 ) {
        if ( null == a1 && null == a2 ) return null;
        int l1 = 0;
        if ( null != a1 ) l1 = a1.Length;
        int l2 = 0;
        if ( null != a2 ) l2 = a2.Length;
        var b = new T[ l1 + l2 ];
        if ( null != a1 ) Array.Copy( a1, b, l1 );
        if ( null != a2 ) Array.Copy( a2, 0, b, l1, l2 );
        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will work for all cases:

```
int[] a1 ={3,4,5,6};
int[] a2 = {4,7,9};
int i = a1.Length-1;
int j = a2.Length-1;
int resultIndex=  i+j+1;
Array.Resize(ref a2, a1.Length +a2.Length);
while(resultIndex >=0)
{
    if(i != 0 && j !=0)
    {
        if(a1[i] > a2[j])
        {
            a2[resultIndex--] = a[i--];
        }
        else
        {
            a2[resultIndex--] = a[j--];
        }
    }
    else if(i>=0 && j<=0)
    { 
        a2[resultIndex--] = a[i--];
    }
    else if(j>=0 && i <=0)
    {
       a2[resultIndex--] = a[j--];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This appears to be a sorted merge, which while useful in its own right (mainly as part of a MergeSort recursive strategy), might be more than the OP was asking for.

Comment: While this solution works, having lot of techniques available since C# and VB.Net was introduced people may not prefer such solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Simple code to join multiple arrays:

```
string[] arr1 = ...
string[] arr2 = ...
string[] arr3 = ...    
List<string> arr = new List<string>(arr1.Length + arr2.Length + arr3.Length);
arr.AddRange(arr1);
arr.AddRange(arr2);
arr.AddRange(arr3);
string[] result = arr.ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another way to do this, that does not require any additional references to internal libraries (expect of course `System.Collections.Generic`)

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, 
                                           IEnumerable<T> second)
{
    foreach(var e in first)
        yield return e;
    foreach(var e in second)
        yield return e;
}
```

This solution is more universal because of the fact that it uses `IEnumerable<T>`, it means that it can merge elements from any two iterators, and returns a third iterator which contains elements from first and second one.

Here is [snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o3DYVO) of example usage.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
ArrayLIst al = new ArrayList();
al.AddRange(array_1);
al.AddRange(array_2);
al.AddRange(array_3);
array_4 = al.ToArray();
```