# Calculating HMACSHA256 using c# to match payment provider example

Tags: c#, security, cryptography

For a payment provider, I need to calculate a hash-based message authentication code, using HMAC-SHA256. That is causing me quite a bit of trouble.

The payment provider gives two examples of orrectly calculated authentication code in pseudo-code. All keys are in hex.

#### Method 1

```
key = 57617b5d2349434b34734345635073433835777e2d244c31715535255a366773755a4d70532a5879793238235f707c4f7865753f3f446e633a21575643303f66
message = "amount=100&currency=EUR"
MAC = HMAC-SHA256( hexDecode(key), message )
result = b436e3e86cb3800b3864aeecc8d06c126f005e7645803461717a8e4b2de3a905
```

#### Method 2

```
message = "amount=100&currency=EUR"
Ki = 61574d6b157f757d02457573556645750e0341481b127a07476303136c005145436c7b46651c6e4f4f040e1569464a794e534309097258550c17616075060950
Ko = 0b3d27017f151f17682f1f193f0c2f1f64692b227178106d2d096979066a3b2f2906112c0f760425256e647f032c2013243929636318323f667d0b0a1f6c633a
MAC = SHA256( hexDecode(Ko) + SHA256( hexDecode(Ki) + message ) )
result = b436e3e86cb3800b3864aeecc8d06c126f005e7645803461717a8e4b2de3a905
```

I tried to write the code to do this, after doing some research, but I keep coming up with different results.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var key = "57617b5d2349434b34734345635073433835777e2d244c31715535255a366773755a4d70532a5879793238235f707c4f7865753f3f446e633a21575643303f66";
        var ki = "61574d6b157f757d02457573556645750e0341481b127a07476303136c005145436c7b46651c6e4f4f040e1569464a794e534309097258550c17616075060950";
        var ko = "0b3d27017f151f17682f1f193f0c2f1f64692b227178106d2d096979066a3b2f2906112c0f760425256e647f032c2013243929636318323f667d0b0a1f6c633a";
        var mm = "amount=100&currency=EUR";

        var result1 = CalcHMACSHA256Hash(HexDecode(key), mm);

        var result2 = CalcSha256Hash(string.Format("{0}{1}", HexDecode(ko), CalcSha256Hash(HexDecode(ki) + mm)));

        Console.WriteLine("Expected: b436e3e86cb3800b3864aeecc8d06c126f005e7645803461717a8e4b2de3a905");
        Console.WriteLine("Actual 1: " + result1);
        Console.WriteLine("Actual 2: " + result2);

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static string HexDecode(string hex)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= hex.Length - 2; i += 2)
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Int32.Parse(hex.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static string CalcHMACSHA256Hash(string plaintext, string salt)
    {
        string result = "";
        var enc = Encoding.Default;
        byte[]
        baText2BeHashed = enc.GetBytes(plaintext),
        baSalt = enc.GetBytes(salt);
        System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 hasher = new HMACSHA256(baSalt);
        byte[] baHashedText = hasher.ComputeHash(baText2BeHashed);
        result = string.Join("", baHashedText.ToList().Select(b => b.ToString("x2")).ToArray());
        return result;
    }


    public static string CalcSha256Hash(string input)
    {
        SHA256 sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] sha256Bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] cryString = sha256.ComputeHash(sha256Bytes);
        string sha256Str = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < cryString.Length; i++)
        {
            sha256Str += cryString[i].ToString("x2");
        }
        return sha256Str;
    }
```

And this is the result I get:

```
Expected: b436e3e86cb3800b3864aeecc8d06c126f005e7645803461717a8e4b2de3a905
Actual 1: 421ce16f2036bb9f2a3770c16f01e9220f0232d45580584ca41768fd16c15fe6
Actual 2: 290f14398bf8c0959dfc963e2fd9c377534c6fec1983025d2ab192382f132b92
```

So with none of the two methods, I can get the result the provider example wants.

**What am I missing here? Is it encoding? Is my hexDecode screwed up?**

Test tool from payment provider: http://tech.dibs.dk/dibs_api/other_features/hmac_tool/

PHP sample code: http://tech.dibspayment.com/dibs_api/other_features/mac_calculation/

Comment: You HexDecode is screwed up indeed. I'd have expected a function that returns a byte[]. You are returning a string that has be stuffed with binary data.

Comment: To be very precise the provider of the example should also specify the character encoding of the message itself, although ASCII would be a pretty good bet. Don't forget, almost all modern cryptographic primitives expect bytes. One byte wrong = fail.

Comment: You don't have to `.ToList()` the `baHashedText` before calling `.Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))`, its unnecessary. You also don't need to `.ToArray()` afterwards. e.g.: `string.Join(string.Empty, baHashedText.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")))`

Answer (score 202, accepted):

**Edit:** You likely are looking for a quick and simple way to do HMAC-SHA256 and not get into the finer details. The original question asks of those finer details which are explained further below.

#### I want to perform a HMAC-SHA256 on a `byte[]` message input

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
private static byte[] HashHMAC(byte[] key, byte[] message)
{
    var hash = new HMACSHA256(key);
    return hash.ComputeHash(message);
}
```

#### I want to perform HMAC-SHA256 but I have a hex string input

In .NET 5 and above, use `System.Convert.FromHexString` like so, (thanks @proximab). If you're on pre-.NET 5, scroll to "Helper functions" which has alternative solutions.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
private static byte[] HashHMACHex(string keyHex, string messageHex)
{
    var key = Convert.FromHexString(hexKey);
    var message = Convert.FromHexString(messageHex);
    var hash = new HMACSHA256(key);
    return hash.ComputeHash(message);
}
```

#### I'm using a strange API service that sort of does HMAC, but it's something custom

Continue reading. You likely want to use "Method 2" below as a reference point and adjust it to however your service wants you to implement HMAC for message anti-tampering.

---

#### How HMAC-SHA256 Works (should you need to know how...)

Here we will compute an HMAC-SHA256 manually (this answers "Method 2" from the original question).

Assume `outerKey`, `innerKey`, and `message` are already byte arrays, we perform the following:

> **Notation:** Assume `A + B` concatenates byte array A and B. You may
> alternatively see `A || B` notation used in more academic settings.

```
HMAC = SHA256( outerKey + SHA256( innerKey + message  )   )
              .          .       `------------------´ .  .
               \          \           `innerData`    /  /
                \          `------------------------´  /   
                 \               `innerHash`          /
                  `----------------------------------´
                               `data`
```

So the code can be broken down into these steps (using the above as a guide):

1. Create an empty buffer `byte[] innerData` the length of `innerKey.Length + message.Length` (again assuming byte arrays)
2. Copy the `innerKey` and the `message` into the `byte[] innerData`
3. Compute SHA256 of `innerData` and store it in `byte[] innerHash`
4. Create an empty buffer `byte[] data` the length of `outerKey.Length + innerHash.Length`
5. Copy the `outerKey` and `innerHash` (from step #3)
6. Compute the final hash of `data` and store it in `byte[] result` and return it.

To do the byte copying I'm using the [`Buffer.BlockCopy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function since it apparently faster than some other ways ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895120/append-2-byte-arrays-in-c-sharp)).

> n.b. There is likely (read: most certainly) a better way to do this using the the new `ReadOnlySpan<T>` API.

We can translate those steps into the following:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
private static byte[] HashSHA(byte[] innerKey, byte[] outerKey, byte[] message)
{
    var hash = new SHA256Managed();

    // Compute the hash for the inner data first
    byte[] innerData = new byte[innerKey.Length + message.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(innerKey, 0, innerData, 0, innerKey.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(message, 0, innerData, innerKey.Length, message.Length);
    byte[] innerHash = hash.ComputeHash(innerData);

    // Compute the entire hash
    byte[] data = new byte[outerKey.Length + innerHash.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(outerKey, 0, data, 0, outerKey.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(innerHash, 0, data, outerKey.Length, innerHash.Length);
    byte[] result = hash.ComputeHash(data);

    return result;
}
```

#### Helper functions

###### `string` -> `byte[]`

You have plain ASCII or UTF8 text, but need it to be a `byte[]`.
Use [`ASCIIEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`UTF8Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or whichever exotic encoding you're using.

```
private static byte[] StringEncode(string text)
{
    var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(text);
}
```

###### `byte[]` -> hex `string`

You have a `byte[]`, but you need it to be a hex `string`.

```
private static string HashEncode(byte[] hash)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

###### hex `string` -> `byte[]`

You have a hex `string, but you need it to be a` byte[]`.

*.NET 5 and above*

```
private static byte[] HexDecode(string hex) =>
    System.Convert.FromHexString(hex);
```

*Before .NET 5* (thanks @bobince)

```
private static byte[] HexDecode(string hex)
{
    var bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

> n.b. If you need a performance tuned version on .NET Framework 4.x, you can alternatively backport the .NET 5+ version (by replacing `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` with `byte[]`). It uses proper lookup tables and conscious about hot-code paths. You can reference the .NET 5 ([MIT licensed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/LICENSE.TXT)) `System.Convert` code [on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7afb66262c287b7832b872473d1e668038aa2496/src/libraries/Common/src/System/HexConverter.cs#L235).

---

For completeness, here are the final methods answering the question using both "Method 1" and "Method 2"

**"Method 1" (using .NET libraries)**

```
private static string HashHMACHex(string keyHex, string message)
{
    byte[] hash = HashHMAC(HexDecode(keyHex), StringEncode(message));
    return HashEncode(hash);
}
```

**"Method 2" (manually computed)**

```
private static string HashSHAHex(string innerKeyHex, string outerKeyHex, string message)
{
    byte[] hash = HashSHA(HexDecode(innerKeyHex), HexDecode(outerKeyHex), StringEncode(message));
    return HashEncode(hash);
}
```

---

We can perform a quick sanity check with a console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string message = "amount=100&currency=EUR";
    string expectedHex = "b436e3e86cb3800b3864aeecc8d06c126f005e7645803461717a8e4b2de3a905";
    Console.WriteLine("Expected: " + expectedHex);

    // Test out the HMAC hash method
    string key = "57617b5d2349434b34734345635073433835777e2d244c31715535255a366773755a4d70532a5879793238235f707c4f7865753f3f446e633a21575643303f66";
    string hashHMACHex = HashHMACHex(key, message);
    Console.WriteLine("Method 1: " + hashHMACHex);

    // Test out the SHA hash method
    string innerKey = "61574d6b157f757d02457573556645750e0341481b127a07476303136c005145436c7b46651c6e4f4f040e1569464a794e534309097258550c17616075060950";
    string outerKey = "0b3d27017f151f17682f1f193f0c2f1f64692b227178106d2d096979066a3b2f2906112c0f760425256e647f032c2013243929636318323f667d0b0a1f6c633a";
    string hashSHAHex = HashSHAHex(innerKey, outerKey, message);
    Console.WriteLine("Method 2: " + hashSHAHex);
}
```

You should have all the hashes line up correctly:

```
Expected: b436e3e86cb3800b3864aeecc8d06c126f005e7645803461717a8e4b2de3a905
Method 1: b436e3e86cb3800b3864aeecc8d06c126f005e7645803461717a8e4b2de3a905
Method 2: b436e3e86cb3800b3864aeecc8d06c126f005e7645803461717a8e4b2de3a905
```

The original code for this answer can be accessed at:
http://pastebin.com/xAAuZrJX

Comment: Awesome answer. I am giving you a bounty for that (in 24 hours, there is some sort of delay in place).

Comment: @Jaxrtech can you attach a license to the code you published in pastebin? 
Say MIT or CC0?

Comment: @Opher as always IANAL, and technically `HexDecode(string hex)` is from @bobince being only 5 lines if you really want to be cutting hairs, so I don't really know if i can technically "re-license" the entire thing since its not *entirely* mine. But I'm sure plenty of people have already outrightly just copy and pasted the entire thing which is what I would imagine SO is partially for and what people intend for. Otherwise, I would feel just to stick the MIT license on top of thing.

Comment: @Opher (cont'd) Of course at the bottom of this page, you can see that "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required" but of course this seems to be in some stupid horrendous mess (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow). In all honesty though, I seriously doubt someone on SO is going to want to pursue a lawsuit over 5 lines of code they posted on SO against who knows who in whatever jurisdiction of the world they may be situated in.

Comment: @JoshBowden Thanks for this solution.
I am getting below error in **hex string -> byte[]** function:
"Input string was not in a correct format."
**StackTrace**: "   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)\r\n   at System.Byte.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style)"
The line 
byte.Parse(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)
is giving this exception. For some hex substring values it is working fine but for some values it is failing.

Comment: In .Net 5 and .Net 6 there is available method for converting hex to byte array
```csharp public static byte[] FromHexString (string s); ```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.fromhexstring?view=net-6.0

Comment: @PrasadKaiche my guess is that your hex string either has illegal characters or the length of the hex was not of an even length

Comment: One example uses a single key, but the other example uses two keys. Both produce the same hash output, so how are the keys derived to produce the same result?

Answer (score 66):

Here's a string extension method for getting a fairly standard HMAC SHA 256 token for a given string:

**usage:**

```
myMessageString.HmacSha256Digest(mySecret)
```

**string extension method:**

```
public static string HmacSha256Digest(this string message, string secret)
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
    System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 cryptographer = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(keyBytes);

    byte[] bytes = cryptographer.ComputeHash(messageBytes);

    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer is beautifully in-depth. But to be quite honest, I felt that it was a lot to digest. I upvoted this because it's: 1) correct, 2) easy to consume intellectually, 3) just so darn simple. Nicely put @Chris Halcrow

Comment: I tried using this, and while it is more concise, it doesn't work for the example 1 provided above. The `byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(secret);` doesn't work for the HEX key provided in the example. It needs to be `byte[] keyBytes = HexDecode(secret);` where HexDecode is shown in the example answer, and originally, in the detailed answer provided by @bobince.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I tried the most voted above solution but it is failing in **hex string -> byte[]** function. Tried your solution and got it working. This solution is short and concise. Thanks again.

Comment: One of the classic examples, why Microsoft's .NET documentation is hated so much. Couldn't understand a thing in their documentation. Your answer saved my day. Thank You.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this method for HMACSHA256.

```
string key = "your key";
string message = "your message";
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);

HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte);

byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
return ByteToString(hashmessage);
```

Here is the ByteToString method:

```
public static string ByteToString(byte[] buff)
    {
        string sbinary = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
        {
            sbinary += buff[i].ToString("X2"); // hex format
        }
        return (sbinary);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A SHA hash is calculated on a sequence of bytes. Bytes are a profoundly different datatype to characters. You should not use character Strings to store binary data such as hashes.

> sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Int32.Parse(hex.Substring(i, 2)...

This creates a character string by reading each encoded byte and turning into a character of the same Unicode code point number. This is equivalent to decoding the bytes 0-255 using the ISO-8859-1 (Latin1) encoding, due to that encoding's property of matching the first 256 code points in Unicode.

> var enc = Encoding.Default; [...]
> baSalt = enc.GetBytes(salt);
>
> byte[] sha256Bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);

These both convert the characters back to bytes using the system default encoding. This encoding varies between installs, but it will never be ISO-8859-1 - even the similar Western European code page 1252 has different characters in the range 0x80-0x9F.

Consequently the byte array you are using doesn't contain the bytes implied by the example hex sequences. A cheap fix would be to use `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` instead of the default encoding, but really you should be using a bytes array to store data in the first place instead of a String, eg:

```
byte[] key= new byte[] { 0x57, 0x61, 0x7b, 0x5d, 0x23, 0x49, ... };
```

and pass that directly into `ComputeHash`.

If you must initialise data from a hex string, parse it directly into a byte array, eg:

```
private static byte[] HexDecode(string hex) {
    var bytes= new byte[hex.Length/2];
    for (int i= 0; i<bytes.Length; i++) {
        bytes[i]= byte.Parse(hex.Substring(i*2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question is answered, but I am posting this in case others need it. Here is a snippet of code created by the payment provider (DIBS):

```
    /**
    * calculateMac
    * Calculates the MAC key from a Dictionary<string, string> and a secret key
    * @param params_dict The Dictionary<string, string> object containing all keys and their values for MAC calculation
    * @param K_hexEnc String containing the hex encoded secret key from DIBS Admin
    * @return String containig the hex encoded MAC key calculated
    **/
    public static string calculateMac(Dictionary<string, string> paramsDict, string kHexEnc)
    {
        //Create the message for MAC calculation sorted by the key
        var keys = paramsDict.Keys.ToList();
        keys.Sort();
        var msg = "";
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            if (key != keys[0]) msg += "&";
            msg += key + "=" + paramsDict[key];
        }

        //Decoding the secret Hex encoded key and getting the bytes for MAC calculation
        var kBytes = new byte[kHexEnc.Length / 2];
        for (var i = 0; i < kBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            kBytes[i] = byte.Parse(kHexEnc.Substring(i * 2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }

        //Getting bytes from message
        var msgBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg);

        //Calculate MAC key
        var hash = new HMACSHA256(kBytes);
        var macBytes = hash.ComputeHash(msgBytes);
        var mac = BitConverter.ToString(macBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

        return mac;
    }
```

http://tech.dibspayment.com/DX/Hosted/HMAC

Comment: During the string conversion at the end, why do we need to remove "-" ?

Comment: I am actually not sure. I got this piece of code from my payment gateway provider.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you saved my time.

```
request.Method = "GET";
string signature = "";
string strtime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ssZ");

string secret = "xxxx";

string message = "sellerid:email:" + strtime; 

var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 

byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);

byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
{
var hash = new HMACSHA256(keyByte);
byte[] signature1 = hash.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
signature = BitConverter.ToString(signature1).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}

request.Headers.Add("authorization", "HMAC-SHA256" + " " + 
"emailaddress=xxx@xx.com,timestamp=" + strtime + ",signature=" + signature);
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private static string GenerateSignature(string data, string signatureKey)
    {
        var keyByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureKey);
        using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
        {
            hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
            return hmacsha256.Hash.Aggregate("", (current, t) => current + t.ToString("X2")).ToLower();
        }
    }
```