# 244 Invalid Encryption Format Fix Invalid encryption flag. Data is Inaccurate

Tags: c#, .net, soap, firstdata

So I am facing this error when execute request to FirstData.com.

> 244 Invalid Encryption Format Fix Invalid encryption flag. Data is
> Inaccurate.

```
 E4.ServiceSoapClient ws = new E4.ServiceSoapClient();

 E4.Transaction txn = new E4.Transaction();
 txn.ExactID = firstData.ExactID;  
 txn.Password = firstData.Password;  
 txn.Transaction_Type = "00";  
 txn.Card_Number = model.CardNumber;  
 txn.CardHoldersName = model.CardHoldersName;  
 txn.DollarAmount = product.Price.ToString();  
 txn.Customer_Ref = product.Name;
 txn.Reference_No = product.ID.ToString();
```

By [developer docs](https://firstdata.zendesk.com/entries/407571-first-data-global-gateway-e4sm-web-service-api-reference-guide) for 00 transaction type we have to send those properties:

CardholdersName

Card_Number

DollarAmount

Expiry_Date

Any clue how to fix this error?

Comment: I'm not sure what you've implemented or not, but it sounds like it may have more to do with; *Important Note about v12 or higher of the Web Service API:  Merchants wishing to use V12 or higher of the API must implement the API HMAC hash security calculation.*

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  Correct. But I refer to v11 API as well as I setup under API settings /transaction/v11   Also I have tried the same code for developer API URL for v11 and it is working fine. I mean I use v11 because there is no ANY example for .NET how to implement HMAC security calculation.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson If u can provide HMAC security calculation for .NET I will be happy 1000%. :)

Comment: @Peretz any Update ??  ...for HMAC-SHA256 this might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185122/calculating-hmacsha256-using-c-sharp-to-match-payment-provider-example

Comment: @pankysharma Yes. I did call to FisrData and they did some change under my account so it is working now. The C# code is completly correct.

Comment: @Peretz thanks for reply any idea to implement automated periodic payments (pre-Auth) 

i.e after $500 after 10 days then again $500 after 10days in the future
Also have you implemented their TransArmor function in which Credit Card (up to 12 digits ) will be stored at firstData's DB & rest 4 digits will be at your DB

Comment: @pankysharma no no... I implemented simple CC input without CVV. And it works great. (U should select E-Commerce option)

Comment: @mertopolitan I am experiencing the same problem with PHP code. Everything working fine with my test account, but for live account with token is not at all working. What change I should make in my first data account ?

Comment: @binoy U have to use E-commerce at the settings of the account under FirstData.com. If not then call them.