# HMAC256 from C# to Javascript returns different results

Tags: javascript, c#, html, hash, hmac

I want to create a HMAC256 key from a string with a HMAC key based on my C# project in Javascript. however, each project has different results and can't seem to find a way to make the results identical.

C# PROJECT

```
private string CalculateHMAC(string hmacKey, string signingstring) {
  byte[] key = PackH(hmacKey) //returns 32 bit array;
  byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingstring);

  try {
    using(HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key)) {
      // Compute the hmac on input data bytes
      byte[] rawHmac = hmac.ComputeHash(data);

      // Base64-encode the hmac
      return Convert.ToBase64String(rawHmac);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to generate HMAC : " + e.Message);
  }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```js
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(byteString, hmacKeyinString);
var msg = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Thank you in advance.

Using CryptoJS in my javascript project

Comment: This is probably going to be really hard to work out, but have a close look at the string you are dealing with, and look for special characters - you may need to escape them before running the HMAC function - when I first tried something similar, I specifically had trouble with backslashes, both in a URL and in a date string. Try and run both functions on a tiny/simple/ASCII string and double-check that you get the same output.

Comment: @MikeBrockington Hi there, the string i'm using is this 'currency:mercacct:merRef:amount:sessionValidity:shipBeforeDate:shopperEmail:skinCode:GBP:Payments:22222.H1324.7622211:12100:2019-07-17:2019-07-17::231233332"'

I'll get back to you with the exact same input.

I have changed some information due to security reasons.

Comment: Have you tried it with a simple string like "test"?  Also is your JS value UTF8?

Comment: Are you directly comparing the output - the other thing that caught me out was that the far end had a different idea of what data was part of the comparison...

Comment: @MikeBrockington Tried this and it has returned different values.

Comment: For a simple string?

Comment: @MikeBrockington Yeah, for a simple string 'Answer' and a simple key '123456789'

Comment: @Pieter Hi, my JS value is UTF-8 yes.

Comment: Is  `hash.toString`  necessary - check what your output looks like before that. One way or another your functions aren't doing the same thing, probably need to tweak a parameter somewhere.

Comment: Try the same values with a few online HmacSHA256 hashers.  That might help you determine whether to focus on C# or JS for the fix.  I noted that online hashers differ and would suggest trying a few

Comment: @MikeBrockington Hash.toString is necessary to ensure that it's readable. Please read my other comment to Pieter.

Comment: @Pieter
After looking at several hashers, it came apparent that my hmac key in c# is getting converted into an array of bytes[32] and inserted into (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key)

For now, I have written up the array in javascript is there a way of passing through the array replacing hmacKeyinString?

Currently getting an error, 'key.clamp is not a function' this is due to the fact that the function CryptoJS.HmacSHA256 doesn't allow arrays to be in the parameter.

Comment: Have a look at the answer here.  It gives a detailed explanation that might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185122/calculating-hmacsha256-using-c-sharp-to-match-payment-provider-example

Answer (score 1):

fixed with this line of code

```
        var wordsKey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('yourkey');

        var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(convertString, wordsKey);
        var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
```