# i need to get the header part to get converted to hmacSha to generate a token

Tags: c#, php, hmac

i have a code of php which generates a token based on the header parameter details.what i need is to use C# code to generate a token of hmacSha256

```
$header = [
'apiKey' => 'pqrstuv-012345678901234567890123456789ab',
'userEmail' => 'test@test.com',
'userFirstName' => 'Raymond',
'userLastName' => 'Smith',
'userId' => 123,
'timestamp' => time()
];
$token = hash_hmac('sha256', http_build_query($header),
'012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789abcd');
```

here is my php code which generate a token using hash_hmac (sha256, ) function . but how can i generate token of hash_hmac256  in c#

Comment: sidenote, you should sort the array (by key) before signing

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Is this any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185122/calculating-hmacsha256-using-c-sharp-to-match-payment-provider-example

Comment: this is not working out for me, i need to pass the secret key on which basis it generate the token,

Comment: one more thing will c# hmac256 will generate the save token as generated by php hmac256 function or it will be different