# C# Checking HMAC SHA256 from API

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, sha256, hmac

I'm trying to validate a hmac sha256 key that an API sends to me in a header. I don't fully understand how to validate this, can anoyone point me in the right direction?

From the API reference:

> Every central webhook POST contains a header field
> "X-Signature-SHA256" with the signature value of the signed body's
> payload. The JSON body is signed with the HMAC SHA256 algorithm based
> on RFC2104, with the "Client Secret" as the signing key.

The following awnser is pretty clear & helpfull:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12253723/4179234

However I feel like I'm missing a string/message that I need to encrypt to get the same hmac sha256 key, as I only have the api client secret to use as a key for the hasing but no message.

Following part is taken from the above stackoverlow awnser, so I convert the api client secret to byte[] and use it for the first input var. But what should message be then in this case?

```
   private static byte[] HashHMAC(byte[] key, byte[] message)
        {
            var hash = new HMACSHA256(key);
            return hash.ComputeHash(message);
        }
```

Comment: According to the description, I would say the JSON body is the message.

Comment: That's it thank you! (Had to trim all whitespaces from the JSON string for it to work)