# How to add 'ff ff ff ff' (HEX) before the data of an byte[] array?

Tags: c#, connection, udp, hex, packet

I am currently programming an emulator for a multiplayer game.
The client sends this to the server: `ÿÿÿÿ2joinParty 61586 110000140b9f842 1 1 0 -1 1 pw 1`.
My program sends `joinParty 61586 110000140b9f842 1 1 0 0 1 pw 1` to the server.
Now when I make it send the `ÿÿÿÿ`'s with it, it sends instead of `ff ff ff ff`, `3f 3f 3f 3f`.
Almost all packets require that `ff ff ff ff`, or else the server rejects the connections.

How can I add them?

Comment: see [Best way to combine two or more byte arrays in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415291/best-way-to-combine-two-or-more-byte-arrays-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] firstArray = new byte[] {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF}; 
byte[] secondArray = [your data here]
byte[] result = firstArray.Concat(secondArray).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is now, when I try to convert 'ff ff ff ff' to an byte array, it returns null or gives me an error. I've tried multiple functions..

Comment: What? The first line of code here creates a byte array filled with ff's.

Comment: Stupid me! Sorry, I'm a little bit sleepy.. I'll try it now.