# Concatenate int and byte

Tags: c#, udp

First, I am very new to c#, so please, bear with me.  I am trying to set 3 ints and 4 bytes to a computer via UDP.  I've used this thread to help with concatenating my variables [Best way to combine two or more byte arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415291/best-way-to-combine-two-or-more-byte-arrays-in-c-sharp).  Currently, I am having an error trying to BlockCopy the bytes into an array.  My array is 12 bytes long and I need bytes 9, 4, 5 and 6.  My code is

```
byte[] UDPPacket = new byte[16];
Buffer.BlockCopy(button[9],0,UDPPacket,0,1);
```

and it is erroring with

```
(parameter)byte[]buttons
```

I believe the `BlockCopy` method works for a bytewise copy of one array to the other.  Any insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `button[9]` is not an array, it's a single byte.

Use the index as offset instead:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(button,9,UDPPacket,0,1);
```