# C# - Problem with AES Decryption - always get null

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am trying to implement image steganography with LSB and everything works except decrypting.

There is my class responsible for encryption and decryption of strings below. Encrypting works fine but `Decrypt` method always returns null:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
   class Encryptor {
    //text to encrypt or already decrypted
    private String decryptedText = "";
    //text to decrypt or already encrypted
    private String encryptedText = "";
    private String key = "";

    public Encryptor setDecryptedText(String text)
    {
        decryptedText = text;

        return this;
    }

    public Encryptor setEncryptedText(String text)
    {
        encryptedText = text;

        return this;
    }
    public Encryptor setKey(String text)
    {
        key = text;

        return this;
    }

    Byte[] getHash(Byte[] hash)
    {
        Byte[] newHash = new Byte[32];
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            newHash[i] = hash[i];
        }

        return newHash;
    }

    Byte[] getIV(Byte[] hash)
    {
        Byte[] newHash = new Byte[16];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 32; i < 48; i++)
        {
            newHash[j++] = hash[i];
        }

        return newHash;
    }

    String EncryptAesManaged()
    {
        SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();

        Byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        Byte[] hash = shaM.ComputeHash(data);

        try
        {
            return Encrypt(decryptedText, getHash(hash), getIV(hash));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }

    String DecryptAesManaged()
    {
        SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        Byte[] hash = shaM.ComputeHash(data);
        try
        {
            return Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText), getHash(hash), getIV(hash));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return "";
    }

    String Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        Byte[] encrypted;
        using (RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs)) { 
                        sw.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText));
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                        encrypted = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            aes.Clear();
        }

        return  Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }
    string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        string plaintext = null;
        using (RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV);
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cs))
                {
                    plaintext = reader.ReadToEnd(); //Here get null
                }

                aes.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }

    public String getEncrypted()
    {
         return EncryptAesManaged();

    }

    public String getDecrypted()
    {
         return DecryptAesManaged();

    }
  }
}
```

Why is `Decrypt()` returning `null` rather than the originally encrypted string?

Comment: (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read), this should                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

Comment: @kelalaka - [`CryptoStreamMode.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostreammode?view=netframework-4.7.2) is the correct mode to use in `Decrypt()`, since the decryption method requires *read access to a cryptographic stream.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show how you use your `Encryptor` class, so your question doesn't quite include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I was able to reproduce the problem with the following test harness:

```
public static void Test()
{
    var key = "my key";
    var plainText = "hello";

    var encryptor = new Encryptor();

    encryptor.setDecryptedText(plainText);
    encryptor.setKey(key);

    var encrypted = encryptor.getEncrypted();

    Console.WriteLine(encrypted);

    var deecryptor = new Encryptor();

    deecryptor.setEncryptedText(encrypted);
    deecryptor.setKey(key);

    var decrypted = deecryptor.getDecrypted();

    Console.WriteLine(decrypted);

    Assert.IsTrue(plainText == decrypted);
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/02HEZe).

Given that, your code has 2 problems, both of which are actually in encryption rather than decryption.

**Firstly**, in `Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)`, you are writing to the `StreamWriter sw`, then flushing the `CryptoStream` and returning the `MemoryStream` contents -- but you never flush or dispose `sw`, so its buffered contents are never forwarded to the underlying stream(s).

To fix this, your code should looks something like:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs)) 
        { 
            sw.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText));
        }
    }
    encrypted = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Now `getDecrypted()` no longer returns a `null` result -- but instead returns a wrong result of `"System.Byte[]"`, as shown in demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LMYFiC).

**Secondly**, again in `Encrypt(...)`, you are effectively encoding your `plainText` twice at this line:

```
sw.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText));
```

`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)` converts the plain text to a byte array, but the `StreamWriter` is also intended to do this job, converting strings to bytes and passing them to the underlying stream.  So, since you are not passing a string to `Write()`, the overload that gets called is [`StreamWriter.Write(Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.write?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_TextWriter_Write_System_Object_):

> Writes the text representation of an object to the text string or stream by calling the `ToString()` method on that object.

Thus what actually gets encrypted is the `ToString()` value of a byte array, which is `"System.Byte[]"`.

To fix this, simply remove the call to `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)` and write the string directly.  Thus your `Encrypt()` method should now look like:

```
static String Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    string encrypted;
    using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write, true))
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(cs)) 
                { 
                    sw.Write(plainText);
                }
            }                   
            // Calling GetBuffer() avoids the extra allocation of ToArray().
            encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)ms.Length)); 
        }
        aes.Clear();
    }

    return encrypted;
}
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6w5fv4) that now passes successfully.

**Disclaimer:** this answer does not attempt to to review your code for security best practices such as secure setup of [salt and IV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27748353/3744182).