# C#, Convert/Join List of arrays into single array

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following list of arrays

```
var list = new List<string[]>();
```

how to use `LINQ` to convert/Join them into a single array

```
string[] singleArray;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done by `SelectMany` operator.

```
var singleArray = list.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray()
```

Comment: Indeed it is [an option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31992557)...