# How to merge 2 string array (not string List)?

Tags: c#

I'm trying this solution but Copy doesn't work with array of string. and I can't change the type of the array.

Any tips?

[Merging two arrays in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/merging-two-arrays-in-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
string[] result = arr1.Concat(arr2).ToArray();
```

or (if you don't want duplicates):

```
string[] result = arr1.Union(arr2).ToArray();
```

or, possibly more efficient, using [Marc Gravells extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547282/284240):

```
public static T[] Concat<T>(this T[] x, T[] y)
{
    if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
    if (y == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("y");
    int oldLen = x.Length;
    Array.Resize<T>(ref x, x.Length + y.Length);
    Array.Copy(y, 0, x, oldLen, y.Length);
    return x;
}
```