# Use c# byte[] image data in vtk

Tags: c#, image, 3d, 2d, vtk

I am using Kitware.VTK toolkit to show 2d images in 3d.

I have image in byte[]. I want to display it in renderviewcontrol of Kitware.VTK using vtkImageviewer. I dont have much idea about VTK.

Is there anyother way to perform the task?
Can anybody help me for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy your byte array into the VTK world and create a `vktImageData` object to use it as `InputConnection`.

```
vtkUnsignedCharArray myCharArray = vtkUnsignedCharArray.New();
GCHandle myPinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(myByteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
myCharArray.SetArray(myPinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject(), myData.Width * myData.Height * myData.Depth, 1);

vtkImageData myVtkImageData = vtkImageData.New();
myVtkImageData.GetPointData().SetScalars(myCharArray);
myVtkImageData.SetScalarTypeToUnsignedChar();

myVtkImageData.SetExtent(0, myData.Width - 1, 0, myData.Height - 1, myData.Depth -1);

myVtkImageData.Update();
```

The `myData` is just a information about the image dimension of your byte array. You should also make sure that the `GCHandle` and `vtkImageData` object is not cleared by the `GC`.

Depending on your data it's probably necessary to set `Origin` and `Spacing`.

Comment: thanks JohnnyQ! It helped. I need some more help here. I have byte array of multiple images and i want to convert them into 3d vtkimage.
It can be done by storing byte data as jpg or bmp images and them load these series of images as 3d in vtk but i dont want to store images instead just want to direct convert them to 3d vtkimage from arrays.

Comment: You could merge your arrays into one and use it as input array, so you get a 3D volume as output.

Comment: Hi JohnnyQ, I am using kitware vtk version 5.6. SetScalarTypeToUnsignedByte() method is not available in it. By using other similar methods, I am not able to create image. I also not get, how t merge image data arrays.

Comment: Corrected the code i meant `SetScalarTypeToUnsignedChar`. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/merging-two-arrays-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/merging-two-arrays-in-net)

Comment: Its still not working. Can you give full code to show image in vtk image viewer.

Comment: The general gist of it. This answer should guide people to the right solution. For me, it helped to set the number of scalar components on the scalar array (not vtkImageData).