# Can ASCII arrays be manipulated as arrays without converting to String form?

Tags: vb.net, concatenation, ascii, arrays

This is a basic question, but I can't find anything on it, since I don't know what to search — each of my tries have come up with unrelated results.

If I use `Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` to convert a string into ASCII, does each byte represent exactly one character? Does the following code work as exactly intended in all circumstances (for all `Strings` other than the examples)?

```
Dim t1() As Byte = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello ")
Dim t2() As Byte = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("World")

Dim msg As String = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(t1.Concat(t2).ToArray)
```

Now `msg` should be `"Hello World"`.

I would like this to work as I don't want to have to convert data I receive back to `Strings` in order to manipulate it before it is sent again.

What if I used something other than ASCII (like UTF-8, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes to convert a string into ASCII, does each byte represent exactly one character?

Yes. ASCII is a 7bit encoding, it does not support multi-byte characters. Any Unicode codepoint above U-007F will get converted to a `?` character in ASCII.

If you were to use UTF-7 instead, for instance, it can encode individual Unicode codepoints into a sequence of multiple ASCII characters.

> Does the following code work as exactly intended in all circumstances (for all Strings other than the examples)?

In your particular example, yes (provided you are using LINQ's [`Concat()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) - there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/) to concat arrays together).  There is no data loss.

But for other examples, just know that you will have data loss if you convert non-ASCII characters to ASCII, or otherwise mismatch encodings between `GetBytes()` and `GetString()`.

You can certainly manipulate byte arrays. Just make sure the arrays are in the same encoding if you merge them together.

Comment: If you prefer an exception to silent data loss via a replacement characters (default is ?) when encoding a character that ASCII doesn't support, you can [create your own encoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx#Exception) based on the standard ASCII encoder.

Answer (score 1):

.NET strings are counted sequences of UTF-16 code units (`char`), one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint (`int` [Char.ConvertToUtf32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2ys180b(v=vs.110).aspx) ). Some codepoints are "combining characters", which when applied to a preceding "base character" form a grapheme (which is then rendered by a font into a glyph).

An encoder from Unicode to an encoding of another character set should attempt to preserve graphemes. In .NET, a grapheme is called a "text element."

So, yes, you can combine encoded byte sequences as long as you haven't defeated the encoder by converting parts of a grapheme into different byte sequences. If you are breaking a string into two before encoding, see [TextElementEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textelementenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) and StringInfo class.