# Is there some syntax for merging tuples similar to spread elements?

Tags: c#

Since C#12 the language supports [Collection expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions), which allows merging collections using a spread element.

My question is, wether or not there is **some simliar syntax for tuples**, especially to combine tuples? (see example below)

```cs
using System;

// Collection expression
int[] arr1 = [1, 2];
int[] arr2 = [3, 4];
int[] arr3 = [..arr1, ..arr2]; // combine using spread element => [1, 2, 3, 4]

// tuples, similar syntax
var tpl1 = (1, 2); 
var tpl2 = (3, 4);

// Sadly this doesn't work? 
var tpl3 = (..tpl1, ..tpl2); // Cannot implicitly convert type '(int, int)' to 'System.Index'
```

---

I know, I could do this:

```cs
var tpl3b = (tpl1.Item1, tpl1.Item2, tpl2.Item1, tpl2.Item2);
```

but it's unhandy for larger tuples or tuples with longer names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging two arrays in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/merging-two-arrays-in-net)

Comment: No, there is no such operator for value tuples (AFAIK). You can suggest one here - https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang.

Comment: @nbk OP wants to merge 2 tuples, not 2 arrays.

Comment: Note, that tuples unlike arrays are restricted: they can't have more than **8** items. That's why you can't put `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) + (6, 7, 8, 9)` and have `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)`

Comment: ValueTuple is struct, so you should not create large tuples. ValueTuple items can have names, how to resolve same names?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko actually you can.

Comment: @GuruStron depending on which datapy his tuple almost all support lingo or have a method to combine,  so her must fist declare his variables and go from there

Comment: @shingo Good point about large tuples, thanks. I would see duplicate names as compiler-error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such operator out of the box. If you have a lot of code like the one in question you can "write" one. Either manually by defining a bunch of the extension methods:

```
public static class ValutTupleExts
{
    public static (T1, T2, T3, T4) Combine<T1, T2, T3, T4>(this (T1, T2) t1, (T3, T4) t2) =>
        (t1.Item1, t1.Item2, t2.Item1, t2.Item2);
    // many-many variants of the code above
}
```

and usage:

```
var tpl3 = tpl1.Combine(tpl2); // tpl3 is (int, int, int, int)
```

Or by can enhancing this approach by using [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) (i.e. write code which will generate methods above) so you don't need do it by hand.

Notes:

- From [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) doc:

  > ❌ AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
  >
  > - ...
  > - It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
  > - ...

  While different `ValueTuple`'s defined in the framework already violate this recommendation I would still recommend to keep it in mind when working with big value tuples and try to avoid using ones with more than 2-4 elements.
- A value tuple with more than 7 elements is actually a value tuple containing a nested value tuple (compiler will handle that for you in many cases but still) - [`ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRest>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-8?view=net-8.0):

  ```
  public struct ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRest> : IComparable, IComparable<(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest)>, IEquatable<(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest)>, System.Collections.IStructuralComparable, System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable, ITuple where TRest : struct
  ```

  i.e. `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` is actually `ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ValueTuple<int>>`.
- If you deem that this feature should be part of the language - consider suggesting it in the [csharplang](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/) repo @github.

Comment: Thanks for all that information, especially the reminder about large tuples.